# Using npm juice2, can I inline styles inside <style> without overriding styles in html style attribute?

Tags: html, css, node.js, npm

Hi im using juice2 from:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/juice2

juice2 correctly inlines those CSS selectors of ... to corresponding HTML tag.
However I have some HTML tags which also have style attribute. ie:

```
<style>
 p { color: black}
</style>

<p style="padding: 10px"> Hi there</p>
```

when I run juice API on a file:

```
 const options = {
  applyStyleTags: true,
  preserveMediaQueries: true
}
juice.juiceFile(ruta, options, (err, html) => {
  console.log(html);
  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(inlinedFile, html);
    // file written successfully
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

})
```

will output:

```
<p style="color: black">Hi there</p>
```

instead of merging both styles:

```
<p style="color: black; padding: 10px;">Hi there</p>
```

Any idea on how to get the desired output? (am I missing any options of juice2 which merges both styles?

Comment: juice2 hasn't been updated in 8 years and I can't get it to compile on my system so I can't test your code. What you describe sounds like a bug and I suggest looking for an alternative.

Comment: juice2 appears to be an unmaintained fork of juice (which was last updated 4 days ago, a much better sign that 8 years ago!) so you should probably use juice instead.

Answer (score 0):

**juice v9.0.0** https://www.npmjs.com/package/juice?activeTab=readme
(not juice2) seems to fix the issue and now correctly merges styles declared unside  tag with those styles inlined in style attribute in HTML tag.

As mentioned above, **juice** seems to be updated while **juice2** is unmaintained

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that the npm juice2 package override your inline CSS and in order to avoid that we can use id selector in your inline style,
for example:

```
<style>
    #my_paragraph{
    color: black;
    }
</style>

 <p id="my_paragraph" style="padding: 10px"> Hi there </p>
```

Comment: That isn't valid HTML. You seem to be confusing it with JSX.

Comment: Re edit: Why would an ID selector interact with a style attribute in a different way to a type selector? They both select the same element.

Comment: It's true that I could have also used the type selector to achieve the same effect but, if you use a type selector, the external styles could still override your inline styles if they are more specific. On the other hand, using a ID selector ensures only that the element with that specific Id will be targeted, and it makes inline styles more specific than any external styles that might apply to the same element. type selector would work but Id selector is more reliable and ensures that your inline styles takes priority over external stylings.

Comment: You're wrong. ID selectors are more specific than type selectors, but **both** are less specific than style attributes however **that doesn't matter** because the style attribute sets a **different property** to the ruleset in the stylesheet.